# DataBuffer difference slice or retainSlice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Can somebody explain the difference between `slice()` and `retainSlice()` from https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBuffer.html ?

I mean: what is a *retained* slice, in contrast to a normal slice? Because both methods create a new, shared buffer.

My goal is to slice a buffer for later logging. Should I then use slice, or retain slice?

Comment: im not sure but i did find this text in the documentation for retainSlice() `Note that unlike slice(int, int), this method will call DataBufferUtils.retain(DataBuffer) (or equivalent) on the resulting slice.`

Comment: Yeah, but what does this mean exactly regarding the buffer content?

Comment: Well you could look into the source code

Comment: Documentation for DataBufferUtils says the following `Increase the reference count for this buffer by one.` which means, if you read from the databuffer its count will decrease by 1 and when it reaches zero it will deallocate the buffer. By calling retain, it will not decrement the count and you can read out the same value multiple times (is my guess)